# Want to edit a file content for Removing the string after the last underscore and before the file extension using Unix commands

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, filenames

I want to edit the file contents in the 2nd row and 2nd column ,which is a file name from that I want to remove the part after the last underscore and before the file extension .

The contents of the file looks like below
Input file contents

```
No|filename|count
01 |com_101_00000_0001_a234.txt|100
```

resultant file content

```
No|filename|count  
01 |com_101_00000_0001.txt|100
```

The number of underscores may vary depending upon the file names present inside the .ctl files.there are multiple files in a folder likes this ,i want to change the contents for all .ctl file in the 2nd row similarly.

```
Operating system details Linux  2.6.32 -696.30.1.e16
GNU/linux
```

Comment: Title does not match question (hence the current answer, it answers the title, but not the body of the question). Please amend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
awk -F\| -vOFS=\| 'NR==2 {sub (/_[^_]*\./,".", $2)}1' file
No|filename|count
01 |com_101_00000_0001.txt|100


NR==2       if record count is 2 (i.e. 2. line)
sub (       `awk` "substitute" function
/_[^_]*\./  regex: match string consisting of multiple non-underscores, delimited by leading underscore and trailing literal dot
,".",       with a literal dot
 $2)        in second field
1           do default action: print
```

Redirect `>` into temp file, and `mv` / `cp` back to original file if desired. For multiple files, run in a `for` loop for all relevant files.

Comment: How can i modify this for multiple files in a directory?Now it works only for one file ,i want to edit the original files ..Also
Can you please help by explaining how it works ? i know F is for field separator,and NR for number of rows ,but the regular expression all together not able to understand how it works ?

Comment: Edited answers in...

Comment: Great thanks for the explanation ,really helped 

for file in *.ctl
do 
awk -F\| -vOFS=\| 'NR==2 {sub (/_[^_]*\./,".", $2)}' "$file" > tmpfile && mv tmpfile "$file" ; done                                                                                                  Something wrong with the code i written ,getting empty files generated.some basic issues i feel ,please help to correct

Comment: I can't find an immediate error in your loop (except a missing `;` in front of `do`). Do you have the desired output for single file execution?

Answer (score 1):

Change the contents of files with regex;

```
perl -pi -e 's/_[^_\.]+(\.)/$1/g' *
```

Old answer before the question changed;
Change file names with regex;

```
rename 's/_[^_\.]+(\.)/$1/g' *
```

It is written in perl, so is portable.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html

Comment: @user1133275 i have edited my question , was wrongly described earlier.i want to edit the file content not the file name